# Android NDK returning C++ pointer works on emulator but not device

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, garbage-collection, java-native-interface

So im trying to keep na instance of a C++ class between my NDK calls, i.e. the new NetPoco pointer does not work, below.

Everything works fine in the simulator but on devices it seems to get caught in an error loop. I am suspecting the GC throws away my pointer object when the program returns from jsonCreate, so that it cant be used later in jsonParse, how do i fix this problem?

(Please note that the only thing changed since the code was working on device is: moving the instantiation of NetPoco from parse to create, i.e. creating a persistent pointer.)

Error loop is shown below the code, the error seems to come from :

```
for(int i = 0; i < ref->storeRefs.size();i++)
```

But im not sure that it does, it seems storeRefs is not retained in ref...

```
long jsonCreate(JNIEnv* aEnv, jobject aObj, jstring str){
    const char * natStr = aEnv->GetStringUTFChars(str,0);
    return (jlong)new NetPoco(natStr);
}


bool jsonParse(JNIEnv* aEnv, jobject aObj, jlong pointer){

    //JSON FROM NETWORK:
    StoreRefListComplexType *ref;
    int iterations = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {

        ref = ((NetPoco*)pointer)->getStoreRefListComplexType();
        if (i < iterations - 1) delete ref;
    }
    //delete netHelper;

    //Callback to populate ArrayList in java:
    jclass cls = aEnv->FindClass("com/example/jsonpoco/MainActivity");
    jmethodID methodid = aEnv->GetMethodID(cls, "add", "(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;DD)V");
    std::list<StoreRefComplexType>::iterator it = ref->storeRefs.begin();
    for(int i = 0; i < ref->storeRefs.size();i++){
        jstring storeNo = aEnv->NewStringUTF(it->getStoreNo().c_str());
        jstring storeName = aEnv->NewStringUTF(it->getStoreName().c_str());
        jstring storeUrl = aEnv->NewStringUTF(it->getStoreUrl().c_str());
        aEnv->CallVoidMethod(aObj,methodid, storeNo, storeName, storeUrl, it->getStoreLocation()->getLatitude(), it->getStoreLocation()->getLongitude());
        std::advance(it, 1);
    }
    //delete ref;
    return ((jboolean)((NetPoco*)pointer)->usingCached);
}
```

> 04-23 10:29:31.928: D/dalvikvm(21469): Trying to load lib
>   /data/app-lib/com.example.jsonpoco-2/libJsonPoco.so 0x417a76b8
>
> 04-23 10:29:31.936: D/dalvikvm(21469): Added shared lib
>   /data/app-lib/com.example.jsonpoco-2/libJsonPoco.so 0x417a76b8
>
> 04-23 10:29:31.967: I/dalvikvm(21469): TRACE STARTED:
>   '/storage/emulated/legacy/jsonjavanc_profiling.trace' 8192KB
>
> 04-23 10:29:31.983: D/dalvikvm(21469): +++ active profiler count now 1
>
> 04-23 10:29:32.404: A/libc(21469): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at
>   0x00000004 (code=1), thread 21469 (xample.jsonpoco)
>
> 04-23 10:29:33.803: D/dalvikvm(21497): Trying to load lib
>   /data/app-lib/com.example.jsonpoco-2/libJsonPoco.so 0x4179efd8
>
> 04-23 10:29:33.811: D/dalvikvm(21497): Added shared lib
>   /data/app-lib/com.example.jsonpoco-2/libJsonPoco.so 0x4179efd8
>
> 04-23 10:29:33.850: I/dalvikvm(21497): TRACE STARTED:
>   '/storage/emulated/legacy/jsonjavanc_profiling.trace' 8192KB
>
> 04-23 10:29:33.865: D/dalvikvm(21497): +++ active profiler count now 1
>
> 04-23 10:29:34.295: A/libc(21497): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at
>   0x00000004 (code=1), thread 21497 (xample.jsonpoco)
>
> 04-23 10:29:34.779: D/dalvikvm(21512): Trying to load lib
>   /data/app-lib/com.example.jsonpoco-2/libJsonPoco.so 0x417a0668
>
> 04-23 10:29:34.779: D/dalvikvm(21512): Added shared lib
>   /data/app-lib/com.example.jsonpoco-2/libJsonPoco.so 0x417a0668
>
> 04-23 10:29:34.819: I/dalvikvm(21512): TRACE STARTED:
>   '/storage/emulated/legacy/jsonjavanc_profiling.trace' 8192KB
>
> 04-23 10:29:34.834: D/dalvikvm(21512): +++ active profiler count now 1
>
> 04-23 10:29:35.264: A/libc(21512): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at
>   0x00000004 (code=1), thread 21512 (xample.jsonpoco)

And the NDK-STACK result:

Exjobbs-MacBook-Pro:android-ndk-r8d exjobb$ ./ndk-stack -sym /Users/exjobb/code/eclipse/NetPocoCache/libs/ -dump /Users/exjobb/log.txt
********* Crash dump: *********
Build fingerprint: 'google/yakju/maguro:4.2.2/JDQ39/573038:user/release-keys'
pid: 8624, tid: 8624, name: xample.jsonpoco  >>> com.example.jsonpoco <<<
signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 00000004
Stack frame #00  pc 00062ff8  /data/app-lib/com.example.jsonpoco-1/libJsonPoco.so (jsonParse+104)
Stack frame #01  pc 00040da1  /system/lib/libdvm.so
Crash dump is completed

*** *Crash dump:* *****
Build fingerprint: 'google/yakju/maguro:4.2.2/JDQ39/573038:user/release-keys'
pid: 8639, tid: 8639, name: xample.jsonpoco  >>> com.example.jsonpoco <<<
signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 00000004
Stack frame #00  pc 00062ff8  /data/app-lib/com.example.jsonpoco-1/libJsonPoco.so (jsonParse+104)
Stack frame #01  pc 00040da1  /system/lib/libdvm.so
Crash dump is completed

*** *Crash dump:* *****
Build fingerprint: 'google/yakju/maguro:4.2.2/JDQ39/573038:user/release-keys'
pid: 8653, tid: 8653, name: xample.jsonpoco  >>> com.example.jsonpoco <<<
signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 00000004
Stack frame #00  pc 00062ff8  /data/app-lib/com.example.jsonpoco-1/libJsonPoco.so (jsonParse+104)
Stack frame #01  pc 00040da1  /system/lib/libdvm.so
Crash dump is completed

*** *Crash dump:* *****
Build fingerprint: 'google/yakju/maguro:4.2.2/JDQ39/573038:user/release-keys'
pid: 8667, tid: 8667, name: xample.jsonpoco  >>> com.example.jsonpoco <<<
signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 00000004
Stack frame #00  pc 00062ff8  /data/app-lib/com.example.jsonpoco-1/libJsonPoco.so (jsonParse+104)
Stack frame #01  pc 00040da1  /system/lib/libdvm.so
Crash dump is completed

*** *Crash dump:* *****
Build fingerprint: 'google/yakju/maguro:4.2.2/JDQ39/573038:user/release-keys'
pid: 8681, tid: 8681, name: xample.jsonpoco  >>> com.example.jsonpoco <<<
signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 00000004
Stack frame #00  pc 00062ff8  /data/app-lib/com.example.jsonpoco-1/libJsonPoco.so (jsonParse+104)
Stack frame #01  pc 00040da1  /system/lib/libdvm.so
Crash dump is completed

**UPDATE:**
So i have been reducing the code and still get the crash, code is now reduced to mere:

```
bool jsonParse(JNIEnv* aEnv, jobject aObj, jlong pointer){

//JSON FROM NETWORK:
StoreRefListComplexType *ref;
ref = ((NetPoco*)pointer)->getStoreRefListComplexType();
jclass cls = aEnv->FindClass("com/example/jsonpoco/MainActivity");
jmethodID methodid = aEnv->GetMethodID(cls, "add", "(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;DD)V");
std::list<StoreRefComplexType>::iterator it;// = ref->storeRefs.begin();
printf(ref->storeRefs.size());
```

The Cause of the crash seems to depend on whetter using wifi or 3g, 3g works! further update will come when i know for sure. Your answers made my code much better though!!

Comment: What is the size of `long` compared to the size of `jlong` and to that of a pointer on each platform? Trying to store a pointer in a non-pointer type is dangerous.

Comment: You also might delete `ref` _twice_. _And_ also maybe access `ref` after it's been deleted.

Comment: removing delete ref yields the same error

Comment: This probably isn't the problem- but you might want to `aEnv->DeleteLocalRef(...)` for your jstrings in the loop. I say this probably isn't, as if it were, you'd expect to get a different error. Also, no horrible ndk stack?

Comment: And you may want to delete `cls` as well. What is the output of `logcat | ndk-stack -sym (your symbol file)`?

Comment: The mystery deepens. Is your emulator on a 64 bit box by any chance but the device you're using 32 bit? Regardless, - always found this easy to forget- your java long will be [64bit](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Long.html). Have you tried casting from (c) `long` to `intptr_t` then to (java) long? There's probably a few SOs on this already.

Comment: tried it : return (jlong)(intptr_t)new NetPoco(natStr);

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28731/discussion-between-tom-and-david-karlsson)